# How do I continue the sequence for the Schröder-Bernstein Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> If $ X, Y$ are sets such that there are one-to-one maps $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g : Y\rightarrow X$, then there is a one-to-one, onto map $h : X \rightarrow Y$.
>
> *proof*. We divide $X$ into three disjoint subsets $X_X$, $X_Y$ , $X_\infty$ with different mapping properties as follows.
>
> Consider a point $x_1 \in X$. If $x_1$ is not in the range of $g$, then we say $x_1 \in X_X$. Otherwise there exists $y_1 \in Y$ such that $g(y_1) = x_1$, and $y_1$ is unique since $g$ is one-to-one. If $y_1$ is not in the range of $f$, then we say $x_1 \in X_Y$ . Otherwise there exists a unique $x_2 \in X$ such that $f(x_2) = y_1$. Continuing in this way, we generate
>   a sequence of points
>
> $x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, \cdots, x_n, y_n, x_{n+1}, \cdots$
>
> with $x_n \in X$, $y_n \in Y$ and $g(y_n) = x_n, f(x_{n+1}) = y_n$.
>   We assign the starting point $x_1$ to a subset in the following way: (a) $x_1 \in X$ if the sequence terminates at some $x_n \in X$ that isn’t in the range of $g$; (b) $x_1 \in X_Y$ if the sequence terminates at some $y_n \in Y$ that isn’t in the range of $f$; (c) $x_1 \in X_{\infty}$ if the sequence never terminates.

When we continue, does that mean that we would then say that "if $x_2$ is not in the range of $g$, then we say $x_2 \in X_X$. Otherwise there exists $y_2\in Y$ ..."?

Also, would we assign $x_2$ and $x_3$ to $X_X$, for example, if the sequence ends at $x_4$?

Comment: If a sequence starting at $x_1$ terminates at some $x_n$ then $x_1,...,x_n \in X_X$... If it terminates at some $y_n$ then $x_1,..,x_n\in X_Y$.... The idea is that $x\in X_X$ if the sequence starting at $x$ has an odd number of terms, but if it has an even number of terms then $x\in X_Y.$